# Which Value does it return for a query which contains same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider a table that contains a column which has a same value for 100 rows and another one unique. while using select query to retrieve the value which row'th value does it return.

Here is my table structure:

```
id column_1
 1       q
 2       q
 3       q
 4       q
 .       .
 .       .
100      q
```

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @UserId INT
SELECT @UserId = Table_1.column_2 FROM [Table_1] WHERE [Table_1].[Column_1] = 'q'
         select @UserId
it returns 100 th row value,
```

May I know why this value came instead of first id which matches condition?

Comment: You don't specify an `ORDER BY` therefore the records could be in any order depending on the query plan produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT @UserId = Table_1.column_2 FROM [Table_1] WHERE [Table_1].[Column_1] = 'q'
```

This produces 100 result rows, each one assigning the @UserId anew.

It seems the last record picked was the one with value 100, so

```
select @UserId
```

returns 100. It could have been any other value from the table, as you didn't specify in which order to read the records, however (i.e. there is no `ORDER BY` clause).

But why do you select all records anyway? You are only interested in one record, the value of which you want to put into the variable. So select only one result value, e.g.:

```
SELECT @UserId = MIN(column_2) FROM Table_1 WHERE Column_1 = 'q'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign values to variables in the `SELECT` clause, all values returned by the query are assigned to the variables one by one, from the first to the last, according to the sort order of the results.

In this case, with 100 rows returned, the value assigned to the variable will be the last value in the result set, which is the one for the 100th row.

If you want to assign the first value that matches your condition, use the `TOP` keyword to limit the number of rows returned. Please keep in mind that without an explicit `ORDER BY` clause, there is no guarantee on the sort order of the output, so you'd better add it if you want consistent results.

Example:

```
DECLARE @UserId INT;
SELECT TOP(1) @UserId = Table_1.column_2 
FROM [Table_1] 
WHERE [Table_1].[Column_1] = 'q' 
ORDER BY id;
```